# Vlookup not working for specific text

Tags: excel, search, text, vlookup

I am working on two sheets of text, Lets say "apples" in sheet1 and i want to find the cells which contains "apples" in sheet2. Below function works for few columns and its not working for few columns even though the text is in both places..

`=VLOOKUP("*"&apples&"*",Sheet2!H4:H499,1,FALSE)`

I think, its because of the text format in sheet2. I removed unwanted chars using "clean" & "trim" function. but still having issue...

Have anyone faced this issue before...?

Update - This looks more of text format issue. I copied to notepad and found no unreadable chars or new lines...

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or examples where it does not match, but actually should match?

Comment: `"its not working"`?? - you should always specify exactly what that means - did you get an error, an expected result or something else, please specify exactly which

Comment: What does the Name 'Apples' refer to?  Also, you are only referencing a single column "H" so how can it work for a few columns?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`=VLOOKUP("*"&apples&"*",Sheet2!H4:H499,1,FALSE)`

please consider using

`=VLOOKUP("*apples*",Sheet2!H:H,1,FALSE)`

Update - changed to deal with asterisk that I didn't see the first time I tried to answer this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried this earlier, but still its not working...! any other clue..?

Comment: Updated above, I didn't notice the asterisk in your question the first time I tried to answer it.  This works for me now...

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your cells, i.e. change `Sheet2!H4:H499` to  `Sheet2!$H$4:$H$499`!

Without doing this, the range you're running the lookup in will move downwards when copying the formula - which is certainly not what you want! :-)

Comment: Thanks Peter.. I missed this issue..Fixed this, but still struggling with original issue..!!

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with this recently.

I wanted to document that I tried:

- look for trailing spaces
- numbers formatted as text
- ensured arrays were reference locked correctly (e.g. put a $ in front of the part of reference that shouldn't change)

When it still didn't work I copied both values into Notepad++ and changed encoding from UTF-8 to Ansi. What I found was there was a strange hidden character in one of the texts. It was like one of the values had been pasted from word and the space as a "special space" or something. You can get this when a dash is not really a dash but an endash etc.

To fix I pasted my range into Notepad++, changed encoding, search/replace all strange characters with nothing then pasted back into Excel. Then it worked just fine.